# Tell Terminal application to use Windows key instead of Control-Shift e.g. for cut/paste?

Tags: terminal, lxterminal

Is there a way to set up custom key mappings for any of the Terminal programs so that I can do things like this:

Windows-C for copy
Windows-v for paste
Windows-x for cut
Windows-t for new tab

I am tired of typing Control-Shift-C for copy, Control-Shift-x for cut etc.

I have xfce-terminal and LXTerminal installed.

Answer (score 1):

The answer in the case of LXTerminal is to go into Preferences, select Shortcuts, and then reprogram each of the shift-control sequences to use the Windows key, which it refers to as Super.

Unfortunately xfce-terminal which is mostly the same doesn't have a Shortcuts tab.

Answer (score 1):

You can remap keys to your preferences system-wide with `setxkbmap` or `xmodmap` if you use the X Windows environment, or by editing `/usr/share/kbd/keymaps` and calling `loadkeys` if you don't have a GUI.

A sample `.xmodmaprc` file:

```
remove mod4 = Super_L Super_R
add control = Super_L Super_R
add shift = Super_L Super_R
```

You'll need to run `xmodmap ~/.xmodmaprc` on systmem startup, e.g. from `/etc/xdg/lxsession/LXDE-pi/autostart`